# Extending ClaimsIdentity?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to customize `ClaimsIdentity`.

The reason being that I don't want to use cookies to hold all the claims because in the context of my application, I have many (hundreds) `Projects` a user could have access to and could easily make the cookie balloon over 4k (which I think is the limit)

Here's my custom class

```
public class CustomIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
{
    public List<string> Projects { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public CustomIdentity(List<Claim> claims, string authScheme)
        : base(claims, authScheme)
    {
        Projects.Add("test data");
    }
}
```

And how the identity is created when a user signs in:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
     new Claim("Id", userId),
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email)
};

var claimsIdentity = new CustomIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
    IsPersistent = true,
    IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now

};

await httpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
```

The problem is that whenever I retrieve the `ClaimsPrincipal` (from the `HttpContext` or `ControllerBase`) the identity is not the one I created when signing in the user, but plain `ClaimsIdentity`.

Is there any way I can change that?

Comment: What exactly does *plain* mean? Do you mean there are no claims at all? Or just that the `Projects` property isn't persisted? I'm also interested to know how you use `Projects` more generally and how you access it.

Comment: I mean I'm not finding an instance of `CustomIdentity` in `User.Identity` but an instance of `ClaimsIdentity`. The 2 claims are there though.

Comment: Why you need to put project into `ClaimsIdentity` , why not make it as a claim ?

Comment: @NanYu From what I understand, claims end up being added to the cookie and as explained above, I don't want to risk having to many claims and going above the 4k limit for the cookie.